# Error: that port is already in use (Ubuntu 18.04 server, not local development)

Tags: django, ubuntu-18.04

I ran `ufw allow 8000` from the `root` account and am now trying to `python manage.py runserver` and it is saying error port already in use.

When I run `(env) justin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu:~/project$ ps -ef | grep python`
I see the following:

```
root       832     1  0 Feb11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root       884     1  0 Feb11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
justin    4225     1  0 Feb16 ?        00:00:49 /home/justin/project/env/bin/python /home/justin/project/env/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 jobzumo.wsgi
justin   12497 12369  0 03:41 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
justin   15455  4225  0 Feb18 ?        00:00:02 /home/justin/project/env/bin/python /home/justin/project/env/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 jobzumo.wsgi
```

Do I need to kill any of these processes? I have been hesitant as I don't want to screw anything up. Or could the issue be coming from elsewhere?

Note: I am trying to run the project from a user I created, not root, but that is only because the project is in the justin/ directory. Don't know if this has any effect. Also, I ran this project on this server before with no issue, saw the default django rocket ship. Thanks for any help.

Also If I tagged this question wrong I apologize, feel free to move it.

Comment: Your `gunicorn` instance is already listening on port `8000` serving the jobzumo application. Why do you want to launch the development server on the production machine anyway?

Comment: @Selcuk truthfully I'm learning as I go. I'm watching a youtube video where the guy walks through deploying with digital ocean and this is what he does about 45 minutes into the hour-long deployment video. He is running from it from `(env) root@ubuntu:/home/mitch/djangoproject python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` , so I tried to match this in my project.

Comment: @Selcuk so with that said I have no reason other than that is what this video is doing

Comment: I can't comment on a video that I haven't seen, but are you sure you are not mixing-and-matching tutorials? It looks like you have already successfully setup a gunicorn server, which is one of the recommended ways to serve Python web apps for production loads. The development server is for, well, development only.

Comment: @Selcuk actually yes I did go about halfway through one tutorial before finding this one. But the step right before trying to run it on the dev server was installing gunicorn and nginx. Anyway, thanks for your response, so I can try and skip this step more or less?

Comment: Yes you should either use `gunicorn` **or** the development server. You can't have them both (or any two network servers) listen on the same TCP port; and you don't need them to.